# How can I put an equation as a figure next to another figure?

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows

I want to put an equation right next to a figure that looks like:

[image]

My current working trial is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (d) at (2,-2);

    \draw (a) node[left]{$v_2$};
    \draw (b) node[right]{$v_4$};
    \draw (c) node[above]{$v_1$};
    \draw (d) node[below]{$v_3$};

    \draw [fill=black] (a) circle (2pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (b) circle (2pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (c) circle (2pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (d) circle (2pt);

    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (a)--(b) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (c)--(a) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (b)--(c) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (c)--(d) ;
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    $A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}\right]$
    \caption{A directed graph with its adjacency matrix.}
\end{figure}
```

That produces:

[image]

Comment: You can also use `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]` on the tikzpicture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `subcaption` package. To have full and control over the alignment, you can put everything in one `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (d) at (2,-2);

    \draw (a) node[left]{$v_2$};
    \draw (b) node[right]{$v_4$};
    \draw (c) node[above]{$v_1$};
    \draw (d) node[below]{$v_3$};

    \draw [fill=black] (a) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [fill=black] (b) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [fill=black] (c) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [fill=black] (d) circle[radius=2pt];

    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (a)--(b) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (c)--(a) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (b)--(c) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (c)--(d) ;
    \path ([yshift=-1ex]current bounding box.south) node[text width=5em] (sca){\subcaption{ }};
    \path node[text width=5em,right=8em of sca] (scb){\subcaption{ }};
    \node at (scb|-a) {$\displaystyle A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}\right]$};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{A directed graph with its adjacency matrix.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change `8em` in `right=8em of sca` to have whatever distance you prefer.

Or just use the classical `subfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (d) at (2,-2);

    \draw (a) node[left]{$v_2$};
    \draw (b) node[right]{$v_4$};
    \draw (c) node[above]{$v_1$};
    \draw (d) node[below]{$v_3$};

    \draw [fill=black] (a) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [fill=black] (b) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [fill=black] (c) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [fill=black] (d) circle[radius=2pt];

    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (a)--(b) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (c)--(a) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (b)--(c) ;
    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (c)--(d) ;
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    $\displaystyle A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}\right]$
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{A directed graph with its adjacency matrix.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here are some off-topic suggestions to make your code a bit shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {a,b,c,d}
     {(90*\Y:2) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,label={[]90*\Y:$v_\Y$}] (\X){}};

    \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (a)edge (b) (b) edge (d) 
    (d) edge (a)  (a) edge (c) ;
    \path ([yshift=-1ex]current bounding box.south) node[text width=5em] (sca){\subcaption{ }};
    \path node[text width=5em,base right=10em of sca] (scb){\subcaption{ }};
    \node at (scb|-b) {$\displaystyle A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}\right]$};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{A directed graph with its adjacency matrix.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Schrödinger's cat!